# Error while processing General Detail Report Query Request : 0x80040402, Unexpected error

Tags: qbxml

While troubleshooting one of the issues on our live machine, I came across multiple instances of below error in QB sync log files. I have confirmed that the sync process abruptly stops once this error occurs.

**Error:**

```
string hresult = 0x80040402
string message = Unexpected error. Check the "qbsdklog.txt" file for possible additional information.
```

I noticed that the error has occurred only when General Detail Report request is sent from our application to QB.

One of the requests sent when the error occurred:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?qbxml version="5.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <GeneralDetailReportQueryRq requestID="3066106">
      <GeneralDetailReportType>BalanceSheetDetail</GeneralDetailReportType>
      <DisplayReport>false</DisplayReport>
      <ReportPeriod>
        <FromReportDate>2013-05-07</FromReportDate>
      </ReportPeriod>
      <ReportAccountFilter>
        <AccountTypeFilter>CreditCard</AccountTypeFilter>
      </ReportAccountFilter>
      <ReportTxnTypeFilter>
        <TxnTypeFilter>All</TxnTypeFilter>
      </ReportTxnTypeFilter>
      <ReportDetailLevelFilter>All</ReportDetailLevelFilter>
      <ReportPostingStatusFilter>Either</ReportPostingStatusFilter>
      <IncludeColumn>TxnID</IncludeColumn>
      <IncludeColumn>TxnNumber</IncludeColumn>
      <IncludeColumn>ClearedStatus</IncludeColumn>
      <IncludeColumn>RunningBalance</IncludeColumn>
      <IncludeAccounts>All</IncludeAccounts>
    </GeneralDetailReportQueryRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Note: We use Quickbooks Web Connector to connect our application to QB.

Can you please helps us resolving the issue?

Comment: Enable SDK logging and post the relevant parts of the qbsdklog.txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be related to QB2013/Enterprise 13.0 R7P issues.

And recently there have been some reports of "unexpected errors" in 2012 R14P.

2013 error definitely occurred during queries, haven't seen 2012 errors occurring from SDK calls yet.